# Sharepoint SSO from an external LDAP-based webapp

Tags: 2013, ldap, single-sign-on

I'm developping a web application based on a Tomcat server with LDAP authentication.
I would like to know if there is a way to "pass" this authentication token to sharepoint 2013, so that when a user click on an external link (eg. http://mysharepointsite.com/library/1/file1.xls), the file opens in the excel web app without asking for credentials.

Is it possible ?

The web application runs on an intranet and will be accessed from a smartphone.
The user won't be logged on a domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What kind of token has your tomcat application generated? Is it SAML or siteminder token? Sharepoint has a secure store service which actually understands claims based token based on windows identity foundation.

Comment: None of those yet, but i'll look into SAML.

Comment: You  may have to use third party DLL to validate the SAML token. If the SAML token is valid then you can  create the SharePoint token in HTTPModule AuthenticateRequest event.